# Core Data INNER JOIN for junction table

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have 2 tables, and would like to `INNER JOIN` them.

- The first table describe the "relationship between group and contact",
- The second table is the "detail of the contact".

"Relationship between group and contact" has the two columns `groupId` and `contactId`.

Now I would like to get multiple contact details.

(I understand this is not the native way of using core data, but right now I would like to get this work first, then update core data to proper structure later)

Right now I separate that into two fetches:

- 1st fetch get an contactId array given a groupId, and
- 2nd fetch will use that contactId array as predicate to fetch contactDetail.

It's working! However, predicate cannot handle more than 1000, so if I get more, it crashes.

Can one suggest how can I set my `predicate`? Any comment is appreciated!

Thanks

```
    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()


            //3 - set the correct table
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
            fetchRequest.entity = entity

            fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20


            // Filter

            var strForPredicate = String()
            strForPredicate = strForPredicate + "id == nil"
            for (var i = 0; i < self.fetchedResult_GroupAndContact.count; i++)
            {
                strForPredicate = strForPredicate + " OR id == \(self.fetchedResult_GroupAndContact[i].contact_id)"
            }
```

Comment: You're using core data wrong. You should never have to use IDs like this. You need to set up a many to many relationship in the object model. I'd suggest reading a core data tutorial. You are making it difficult for yourself.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code - I have to concur with Fogmeister.

Comment: You might also want to read the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) focussing on the IN operator.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback!